# Why imagicmagick compare giving unrecognized metric 'phash' error?

Tags: imagemagick, ubuntu-14.04

I am running following command to compare phash of two images in ubuntu terminal

```
compare -metric phash 01.png 02.png compare.png
```

but it giving error that:

```
compare.im6: unrecognized metric type `phash' @error/compare.c/CompareImageCommand/728
```

my identify version is:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because the phash metric has been added in version 6.8.8-2. I would advise you to upgrade to the latest version if you need this feature.

Comment: i tried to upgrade my imagemagick following link http://askubuntu.com/questions/267746/how-can-i-install-the-latest-upstream-version-of-imagemagick-without-compiling. but it did not upgrade can anyone help???